# Making the font size larger than \HUGE in chapter headings with memoir?

Tags: memoir, chapters, fontsize

How would one go about this? Below my MWE. I should note that `\HUGE` appears no different from `\Huge`, but I decided to use it anyway as it should be the largest option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\input{preface}

\usepackage{egothic}%

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{ene}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}%
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\hfill\egothfamily\HUGE}%
}
\chapterstyle{ene}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{1}
This is the first chapter.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [anyfontsize](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize)-package?

Comment: Note that the `egoth` font is only available in bitmap format.

Comment: @egreg: Hurm. Might not look good in large print, then?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard Unless you set a high resolution, it will look bad at every size.

Comment: @egreg: Hurm. I switched to plain `yfonts`/`frakfamily`, much crisper to behold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're free to create a new macro called, say, `\YUGE` (sorry, I couldn't resist!), as

```
\newcommand\YUGE{\fontsize{48}{60}\selectfont}
```

or, if you want to go overboard completely, as

```
\newcommand\YUGE{\fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont}
```

and then use `\YUGE` inside the definition of `\chaptitlefont`.

Comment: This works! What do the numbers 100 and 120 represent?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard - The macro `\fontsize` takes two arguments, which should be positive numbers. The first number is the font size, expressed in "TeX points" (close, but not identical, to "Adobe points"), and the second number is the "baseline skip" (expressed in TeX points), which is a typographers' term for the distance between consecutive lines of text. Usually, the baseline skip is set to be about 20% larger than the font size. There are some important exceptions, though. E.g., if you were using a Fraktur-type text font, you should use the same number for both arguments of `\fontsize`.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I had trouble Googling it and only found the answer after your comment was posted. Given the font is `egothic`, would the Frakur-rules apply?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard - To my eyes, `egothic` doesn't look particularly "gothic" or "fraktur-like" at all. If it were up to me, I'd call that font a "really awful adaptation of some 'Insular' font". (What's particularly bad about the font is the poor kerning between many glyph combinations.) You should feel free to set the baseline skip either to the value of the font size or to 10% more than the value of the font size; choose whatever appeals to you the most. You're in trouble as it is with this font; varying the baseline skip isn't going to make much of a difference. Sorry.

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard - If your chapter headers span two or more lines, you should definitely remove the `\hfill` directive from the definition of `\chaptitlefont`. On the other hand, if your chapter titles take up a single line, there's no reason to worry about the baseline skip value -- it only matters if there's more than one line of text...

Answer (score 3):

When you want larger font sizes than usual with `memoir` you have to use the `extrafontsizes` option (and scalable, not bitmap, fonts).

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\begin{document}
  normal {\huge huge} {\Huge Huge} {\HUGE HUGE}
\end{document}
```

or to get really big fonts, for instance

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,60pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
  normal 60pt \\ {\HUGE HUGE \\ 132pt}
\end{document}
```

but you have to be careful about line spacing.